# Regexp to replace string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below string pattern like Below.

`"XX0XX XX7XX XX11XX XX26XX XX30XX XX38XX XX45XX **3** 10.1, Belkin Keyboard Folio"`

I have to replace last `"3"` with `"XX49XX"` which does not have prefix and suffix with `"XX"`

I have done below code so far which is replacing first occurrence of 3 which is not correct

```
var string = 'XX0XX XX7XX XX11XX XX26XX XX30XX XX38XX XX45XX 3 10.1, Belkin Keyboard Folio';

str = string.replace(/3/, 'XX49XX');
```

Comment: Replace them with what? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: You need to edit your question to make it clear exactly what is your input, your desired output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have below string pattern I have to replace last "3" which does not have prefix and suffix XX



var string = 'XX0XX XX7XX XX11XX XX26XX XX30XX XX38XX XX45XX 3 10.1, Belkin Keyboard Folio';

str = string.replace(/3/, '__49__');

Comment: There is an "edit" link under your question, you should use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While JS sadly doesn't have the capacity for lookbehinds, you can use a lookahead:

```
string.replace(/3(?!\d*XX)/, "XX49XX");
```

This will ensure that the `3` that you get is not part of a `XX##XX` structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use use negative lookahead to match last `3`:

```
string = string.replace(/3(?!.*3)/, 'XX49XX');

// XX0XX XX7XX XX11XX XX26XX XX30XX XX38XX XX45XX 49 10.1, Belkin Keyboard Folio
```

Answer (score 0):

anubhave shows how to match the last occurence of the digit 3.

You can also match to the relevant part of the string.

```
string.replace(/\b\d+ (\d+\.\d+, Belkin Keyboard Folio)/, 'XX49XX')
```

This replaces the first number (one or more digits) in the substring with the form `<number> <number>.<number>,Belkin Keyboard Folio`